# How to put data on jrxml file from Java?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Hi have this code sample from my .jrxml file.

```
<staticText>
    <reportElement x="69" y="10" width="422" height="180" uuid="52dc00c8-2cd3-466e-bc37-9dde8d5da625"/>
    <textElement textAlignment="Justified" markup="html">
        <font size="11"/>
        <paragraph lineSpacing="1_1_2"/>
    </textElement>
    <text><![CDATA[I HAVE THINGS HERE]]></text>
</staticText>
```

On the text tag i wanna have a String thats coming from a Java class. How do i do that? 
Here is the Java code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     try {
        JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager
            .compileReport("src/main/resources/EJA1.jrxml");
        Long now = new Date().getTime();
        Map parameters = new HashMap();
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, new JREmptyDataSource());
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint,
            "src/main/resources/reports/teste" + now.toString() + ".pdf");
    } catch (JRException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can use parameter  and textField

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

Thanks Alex K for pointing out my original solution was wrong for `staticText`.

Change your element from `staticText` to `textField`, and then in your CDATA just put your Java class name and constant.  Something like this:

```
<![CDATA[Foo.Bar]]>
```

assuming you have

```
public class Foo {
    public final static String Bar = "bar";
    ...
```

For example, here is how I rendered a string that comes from a Java class:

```
<pageHeader>
    <band height="30" splitType="Prevent">
        <frame>
            <reportElement style="pageHeader" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="940" height="30"/>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement style="pageSubHeaderText" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="940" height="30"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[SomeHelper.someMethod()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </frame>
    </band>
</pageHeader>
```